# SwiftUI PhotosPicker remove location data by default

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, location, photospicker

I have a SwiftUI PhotosPicker that allows users to pick any media type (images, videos, Live Photos, etc) for the purpose of file sharing.

I load the transferable objects using FileRepresentation to A) Support any file type easily and B) minimize load / reduce memory usage when loading many files. I share the URL file representation via a SwiftUI ShareLink so I never deal with the actual raw file type. Just the File URLS.

By default these files include location data. The user would have to go to the Settings app to alter this, or manually remove location in photo picker settings after each selection.

I have no need for the location data and would prefer not to have it at all. Mostly to gain user trust. Have had complaints from users who were not happy with this being the default setting.

Any way to set location off in SwiftUI PhotosPicker by default?